# MYSQL counting returns nothing for a where statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table of the form:

```
user_id |  categories
---------------------
   1    | ['apple','orange']
   2    | ['apple','banana']
   1    | ['apple','squash']
   3    | ['fig']
```

I want to summarize the count of 'apple' for each user to give:

```
user_id |  apple_count
---------------------
   1    | 2
   2    | 1
   3    | 0
```

So I thought it would be something like:

```
SELECT user_id, Count(categories) AS apple_count 
    FROM table 
       WHERE categories LIKE     
       '%apple%' 
       GROUP BY user_id;
```

which unfortunately returns:

```
user_id |  apple_count
---------------------
   1    | 2
   2    | 1
```

I was thinking maybe I can solve this with a left-join on all unique user id's, and append 0's to them? But what would be an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You shouldn't store arrays/lists in single columns. If you have the option to change the database design you should normalize it and add a junction table for the many-to-many relation between users and categories. Then you wouldn't struggle with queries like this, plus you would ensure data integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the last part because of the `WHERE` condition. Change your query a little using a `CASE` statement and include the condition in an aggregate function itself like below:

```
SELECT user_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN categories LIKE '%apple%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apple_count 
FROM table 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Jpw's comment is a better answer, however.